# create a type I can enumerate on

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to enumerate on a type.
For example if I declare:

```
type myType = 'value1' | 'value2';
```

Then  I would like to initialize `myTypeArray` with all the values of `myType`.

```
let myTypeArray: myType[] = // enumerate on the values authorized by `myType`.
```

Is there a structure with typescript that allows that ?

Answer (score 2):

You can not do that with type alias because they are not compiled into the javascript output and therefore are not available at runtime.

You can do something similar with [string enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-4.html#string-enums):

```
enum MyType {
    Value1 = "value1",
    Value2 = "value2"
};

let myTypeKeys: string[] = Object.keys(MyType);
console.log(myTypeKeys); // ["Value1", "Value2"]

let myTypeValues: string[] = Object.keys(MyType).map(key => MyType[key]);
console.log(myTypeValues); // ["value1", "value2"]
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=enum%20MyType%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20Value1%20%3D%20%22value1%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20Value2%20%3D%20%22value2%22%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Alet%20myTypeKeys%3A%20string%5B%5D%20%3D%20Object.keys(MyType)%3B%0Aconsole.log(myTypeKeys)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5B%22Value1%22%2C%20%22Value2%22%5D%0A%0Alet%20myTypeValues%3A%20string%5B%5D%20%3D%20Object.keys(MyType).map(key%20%3D%3E%20MyType%5Bkey%5D)%3B%0Aconsole.log(myTypeValues)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5B%22value1%22%2C%20%22value2%22%5D))